# Searching for a word in C++ string s in vectors

Tags: c++

I have a task to find words passed through a cmd line arg into a c++ program that are store in a vector in some text where each line of text is a new item in a vector. The only issue I am having is the actual searching.  Here is my searching code. It either simply does not work or else locks and crashes and burns.

```
while (i < size)
{
    line = inputText[i];
    for (int k = 0; k < kwSize; k++)
    {
        if (line.find(keyWords[k]) != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << "Success" << keyWords[k];
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: can we see the declarations of the variables you are using  ?

Comment: If it doesn't work, what is the bad output? If it locks, on what line of code? If it crashes, what is the error message and what line of code? Also this copies the string `line = inputText[i];` which is inefficient.

Comment: I'm confused. Each element in the vector is a whole line?

Comment: sample input/output would be helpful also :)

Comment: Are you aware that you are copying the string with the instruction `line = inputText[i];` It would be more efficient to write `const auto& line = inputText[i];`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
std::vector<std::string> inputText;
std::vector<std::string> keyWords;
```

Where you need to find any of the keyWords in any of the lines, this is the cleaner way to do it:

```
for (auto line = inputText.begin(); line != inputText.end(); ++line)
    for (auto word = keyWords.begin(); word != keyWords.end(); ++word)
        if (line->find(*word) != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << "Success" << *word;
        }
```

This shouldn't crash as long as the vectors aren't already corrupted in some way.

Comment: If you are going the auto iterators route, I suggest `cbegin` etc

Comment: @NeilKirk: is there any real difference?

Comment: @NeilKirk: in other words, is there any difference in the generated machine code?

Comment: No it's to detect bugs. Searching shouldn't modify the data.

Comment: @NeilKirk: I would usually define the iterator as `const auto`. In that case, does it matter if I call `begin()` or `cbegin()`?

Comment: Yep, `const auto` doesn't do what you think it does, did you try it? :)

Comment: @NeilKirk: I didn't try modifying the value through const iterator, but I see what you mean. The iterator object is `const`, but that does not prevent me from modifying the object it refers to. Good catch. I'll start using `cbegin` / `cend` from now on!

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code built into an application (VS) that does work.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int size = 5;
string keyWords[size] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "six"};
string inputText[size] = 
{
    "This is one test",
    "This is two test",
    "This is three test",
    "This is four test",
    "This is five test"
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i = 0;

    string line;
    while (i < size)
    {
        line = inputText[i];
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
        {
            if (line.find(keyWords[k]) != std::string::npos)
            {
                cout << "Success" << keyWords[k];
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    char inchar;
    cin >>  inchar;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be prefered not to use compiler-specific constructs, such as `_tmain` in your answer for a general programming problem.

Comment: @Neil: Alas, I'm on my Visual Studio development machine today.  My goal is to instruct, not hand-feed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
std::vector<std::string> inputText;
std::vector<std::string> keyWords;
```

Using C++11 you can also write the following

```
for (const auto& line : inputText)
    for (const auto& word : keyWords)
        if (line.find(word) != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << "Success" << word << endl;
        }
```